# Why won't cpplint work on my raspberry pi?

Tags: pip, cpplint

I am trying to install cpplint on my raspberry pi (has to be cpplint, its for a class). It says it was installed successfully when I run pip3 install cpplint, but then when I go to use it, it does not work.

Comment: In what way it does not work? What is the error?

Comment: When I run "pip3 install cpplint", it says that it has been installed successfully. However, when I run "which cpplint", nothing happens. I believe it should tell me the file location of cpplint if it had been installed, but nothing shows up. And when I try to use cpplint, the program cannot find it.

Comment: `pip3 show --files cpplint`

Comment: I still don't understand why cpplint is there, but won't work. I found the file location using the show --files, but when I run cpplint, it just says "cpplint: command not found".

Comment: That means the location is not in `$PATH`.

Comment: Also try `python3 -m cpplint`.

Comment: How would I add it to the $PATH? I'm fairly new to this OS

Comment: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=add+PATH